# Form Display through JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to display different fields of the form according to selection. It is working properly till few stages. At 6th page, the page refreshes automatically without any input from my side. My code is below. Please help me gettiig out of this error. The actual working page can be found [here.](http://oonline.in/newapp)

```js
function next(idshow,hide){
$("#page"+hide).hide();
$("#page"+idshow).show();
return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My Survey </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12" id="page1">
<h1>WELCOME TO ONLINE 
SURVEY </h1>
<button id="1" onclick="next(2,1)">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="page2" style="display:none">
<center><h1>IMPORTANT</h1> </center>
<p> If you Accept the terms and conditions and provide a relevant information, then you may get UPTO 1 year free trial of apps developed by company in future. </p>
<button id="2" onclick="next(3,2)">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="page3" style="display:none">
<h2><center> This app is only for survey and not responsible for any claims made by company.</center></h2>
<h3> <center>TERMS AND CONDITIONS </center></h3>
<p>1.   IF YOU ACCEPT THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU GET UPTO 1 YEAR FREE TRIAL  OF  APPS MADE BY COMPANY (for purpose the survey is done). </p>
<p>2.   AFTER ACCEPTING THE  TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOLLOWING POINTS ARE BOUND TO THE CLIENT: <br>
a)  You must provide all information which is asked by the company. <br>
b)  In future, if required you provide more information if asked. <br>
c)  If after accepting the terms and condition, not providing or non-cooperating in collecting relevant information, the company have all authority to cancel the contract . <br>
d)   In future company has all powers to change the terms and conditions without prior notice. <br>
e)  If any new clause to be added also accepted by the client. <br> </p>
<button id="3" onclick="next(4,3)">ACCEPT</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="page4" style="display:none">
<p align="center"><strong>ARE YOU PROFESSIONAL?</strong></p>
<p><form name="myform" method="POST"> <input type="radio" name="r1" onclick="next(5,4)" value="YES">YES </p>
<p> <input type="radio" name="r1" onclick="next(17,4)" value="NO">NO </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="page5" style="display:none">
<h2> Personal Information</h2>
  <p>Profile Picture <input type="file" id="pic" class="myinput" name="sbm" align="left" accept="image/*"  value="Browse"> &nbsp;</p>
<p>
FIRST NAME :
</p>
<p>     
  <input type="text" class="nm" name="name" id="name">
</p>
<p>
MIDDLE NAME:
</p>
<p> <input type="text" class="nm"  name="mname" id="nm">
</p>
<p>
LAST NAME :
 </p>
 <p>
  <input type="text" name="lname" class="nm" id="nm">
</p>

<p>
QUALIFICATION
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="qual" id="qual">
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p id="hd1"> example(MBBS,BHMS,DHMS ETC)
</p>

<p id="hd2">
DESGINATION:
</p>
<p> <input type="text" name="desg" id="desg">
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>example(genral practioner, surgeon, skin specialist etc)
</p>
<p>
EXPIRENCE:
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="expi" id="expi">
</p>
<p>
<button id="5" onclick="next(6,5)">NEXT</button>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="page6" style="display:none">
<h1> This is Page 6 </h1>
<button id="6" onclick="next(7,6)">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="page17" style="display:none">
<h1> This is Page 17</h1>
<button id="17" onclick="next(18,17)">NEXT</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="page18" style="display:none">
<h1> This is page 18 </h1>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me understand what problem is there actually??

Comment: Added working code below

Comment: <form name="myform" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">

Try replace form opening tag with the given above. It will not submit the form on clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify type="button" in your button attributes tag like this

```
<button type="button" id="5" onclick="next(6,5)">NEXT</button>
```

If you are using button without specifying the type it will work as submit button for containg form.

your previous button 1,2,3,4 works because they are not inside form tag

Answer (score 1):

1. Id's assigned to buttons are only numbers id should start with
   character and can contain alphabets,numbers and '_'.
2. Your form tag should start after body open.
3. Validate duplicate Id's in your page.
4. Replace add button type as "button". e.g. `<button type="button" id="b1">`

Fix these problems your html page will work properly.

Added working code below

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My Survey</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
 function next(idshow, hide) {
  $("#page" + hide).hide();
  $("#page" + idshow).show();
  //return false;
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>


 <div class="col-md-12" id="page1">
  <h1>WELCOME TO ONLINE SURVEY</h1>
  <button type="button" id="b1" onclick="next(2,1)">NEXT</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12" id="page2" style="display: none">
  <center>
   <h1>IMPORTANT</h1>
  </center>
  <p>If you Accept the terms and conditions and provide a relevant
   information, then you may get UPTO 1 year free trial of apps
   developed by company in future.</p>
  <button type="button" id="b2" onclick="next(3,2)">NEXT</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12" id="page3" style="display: none">
  <h2>
   <center>This app is only for survey and not responsible for
    any claims made by company.</center>
  </h2>
  <h3>
   <center>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</center>
  </h3>
  <p>1. IF YOU ACCEPT THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU GET UPTO 1 YEAR
   FREE TRIAL OF APPS MADE BY COMPANY (for purpose the survey is done).
  </p>
  <p>
   2. AFTER ACCEPTING THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOLLOWING POINTS ARE
   BOUND TO THE CLIENT: <br> a) You must provide all information
   which is asked by the company. <br> b) In future, if required
   you provide more information if asked. <br> c) If after
   accepting the terms and condition, not providing or non-cooperating
   in collecting relevant information, the company have all authority to
   cancel the contract . <br> d) In future company has all powers
   to change the terms and conditions without prior notice. <br> e)
   If any new clause to be added also accepted by the client. <br>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="b3" onclick="next(4,3)">ACCEPT</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12" id="page4" style="display: none">
  <p align="center">
   <strong>ARE YOU PROFESSIONAL?</strong>
  </p>
  <p>

   <input type="radio" name="r1" onclick="next(5,4)" value="YES">YES
  </p>
  <p>
   <input type="radio" name="r1" onclick="next(17,4)" value="NO">NO
  </p>
 </div>
 <form name="myform" method="POST" action="">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="page5" style="display: none">
   <h2>Personal Information</h2>
   <p>
    Profile Picture <input type="file" id="pic" class="myinput"
     name="sbm" align="left" accept="image/*" value="Browse">
    &nbsp;
   </p>
   <p>FIRST NAME :</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" class="nm" name="name" id="name">
   </p>
   <p>MIDDLE NAME:</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" class="nm" name="mname" id="mnm">
   </p>
   <p>LAST NAME :</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="lname" class="nm" id="lnm">
   </p>

   <p>QUALIFICATION</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="qual" id="qual">
   </p>
   <p></p>
   <p id="hd1">example(MBBS,BHMS,DHMS ETC)</p>

   <p id="hd2">DESGINATION:</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="desg" id="desg">
   </p>
   <p></p>
   <p>example(genral practioner, surgeon, skin specialist etc)</p>
   <p>EXPIRENCE:</p>
   <p>
    <input type="text" name="expi" id="expi">
   </p>
   <p>
    <button type="button" id="b5" onclick="next(6,5)">NEXT</button>
   </p>
  </div>
 </form>
 <div class="col-md-12" id="page6" style="display: none">
  <h1>This is Page 6</h1>
  <button type="button" id="b6" onclick="next(7,6)">NEXT</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12" id="page17" style="display: none">
  <h1>This is Page 17</h1>
  <button type="button" id="b17" onclick="next(18,17)">NEXT</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12" id="page18" style="display: none">
  <h1>This is page 18</h1>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent `form`'s submitting action by adding `onsubmit="return XXX();"` in your `form` element.

Answer (score 1):

The button submits the form, as its default function. It doesn't reach the return false in your function and I am suspecting because of the little content on this pages.

Since you are including JQuery, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div.col-md-12').hide();
        $('#page' + $(this).data('show')).show();
    });
});
```

This will give all buttons an onclick event and you will not have to repeat the onclick and function on each one.

The above will hide the button's parent div with class col-md-12 and show the div with id page + the value from the button (see below)

Then the button should become:

```
<button data-show="2">NEXT</button>
```

On data show attribute you enter the id of the next div you want to show.